# Custom 404 route not matching website root

Tags: perl, url-routing, mojolicious

I have a few routes defined for my Mojolicious app and a catch-all 404 route:

```
$r->any('*')->to(cb => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render(text => '404 Not Found');
    $self->rendered(404);
});
```

The 404 route works fine:

```
$ ./bin/myapp.pl -m production get /no_such_url
404 Not Found
```

But I also want the 404 route to match the website root, and I always get some default Mojolicious 404 instead, even in production mode:

```
$ ./bin/myapp.pl -m production get /
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Page not found</title></head>
…
```

What do I need to do to serve my plain 404 callback on `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `any '*'` will not catch the main index `/`.  That appears to be the one exception.  There are two easy solutions:

You can just create an alias to your route.  Note how we set the rendered code before we set the rendered text:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

sub my404 {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->rendered(404);
    $self->render(text => '404 any *');

}

any '*' => \&my404;
any '/' => \&my404;

app->start;
```

You can also just override the default 404 not found template as documented in [`Rendering exception and not found pages`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Rendering_exception_and_not_found_pages):

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ not_found.development.html.ep
404 default template
```

Comment: I went the explicit `/` route, thanks! By the way, do I need to set the rendered code *before* setting the text? My code works fine the other way around.

Comment: Yes, specify your code before the text.  If you actually inspect your header, you'll see you're getting a 200 OK if you specify the text first.

Comment: …but my test case explicitly tests for `status_is(404)` and passes. What gives?

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the logging.  I inspected the headers sent to the browser in both cases, and they set 404 Not Found properly.  However, mojo logs the response with a code set after text as 200 OK.  Therefore your test case will work properly, but the logs won't have the right data.